# Using Aurelia UX in a Cordova application (fails to build for iOS)

Tags: cordova, requirejs, aurelia

I've build a web-app using Aurelia CLI (`v0.32, Typescript, Require.JS`) + `Aurelia UX (v0.6.0)`. Using [Brett Nelson tip](https://wipdeveloper.com/2016/11/21/cordova-with-aureli-cli/), I'm building this web-app for `Cordova (v8.0.0)`. Everything works fine when running in browser platform (`cordova run browser`) but it fails when running for IOS (`cordova run ios`)

Here is the error:

[image]

I'm surprised to see that only Aurelia UX dependencies (except `core`) fails to load. I'm suspecting an issue with either require.js or due to the `@` symbol in dependencies name.

Here is how I've declared the dependencies in `aurelia.json`

```
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/core",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/core/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/button",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/button/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/input",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/input/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/icons",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/icons/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/form",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/form/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/checkbox",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/checkbox/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/radio",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/radio/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/datepicker",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/datepicker/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/textarea",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/textarea/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/chip-input",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/chip-input/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
```

And then how I call them from the `main.ts` file

```
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .plugin('aurelia-animator-css')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/core')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/form')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/button')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/input')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/icons')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/checkbox')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/radio')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/textarea')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/datepicker')
  .plugin('@aurelia-ux/chip-input')
```

How do I avoid the problem with Aurelia UX dependencies ?

Comment: As a side note: this issue only started to happen since Aurelia UX 0.4.0 and the move to the mono-repo architecture (and the move into @aurelia-ux org npm scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the resources included in the Bundle. To make the bundle works correctly in Cordova, we must explicitly mention references to all the JS files included in each plugin. The resource key for each plugin in `aurelia.json` must look like this: `"resources": ["**/*.{js,css,html}"]` (with the **js,**) part.

Final `aurelia.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/core",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/core/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/button",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/button/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/input",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/input/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/icons",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/icons/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/form",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/form/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/checkbox",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/checkbox/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/radio",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/radio/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/datepicker",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/datepicker/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/textarea",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/textarea/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/chip-input",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/chip-input/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{js,css,html}"
  ]
},
```